# Convert NSARRAY to NSDictionary to be used as a result of JSon serialisation swift4 Xcode 9

Tags: swift, nsarray, converters, nsdictionary

I want to convert a `NSArray` to a `NSDictionary` and thereafter choose the keys and the values in the `NSDictionary` to be able to later on add the data from the `NSDictionary` to a object by using the keys in it.

How can I do this in the smartest way?

Here's what I have so far:

```
func makeCall(completion: result: NSDictionary or Dictionary){
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:  JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? Array<Any>
}
```

The two JSON files look nearly the same. The difference is the var type so you will get keys and values but in an array style. We need it in a dictionary style to get the values by their keys.

Comment: Could you add an example so your question becomes more clear?

Comment: dont use NS classes in Swift where possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 4**

In Swift you should rather use Dictionary, and only use NSDictionary if you explicitly need that type.

```
    //your NSArray
    let myArray: NSArray = ["item1","item2","item3"]

    //initialize an emtpy dictionaty
    var myDictionary = [String:String]()

    //iterate through the array
    for item in myArray
    {
        //add array items to dictionary as key with any value you prefer
        myDictionary.updateValue("some value", forKey: item as! String)
    }

    //now you can use myDictionary as Dictionary
    print ("my dictionary: ")
    print (myDictionary)

    //if you prefer to use it as an NSDictionary
    let myNSDictionary = myDictionary as NSDictionary!
    print ("my NSDictionary: ")
    print (myNSDictionary)
```

Comment: we get the data from a Json file and we put it in an array. the Json file is looking like this type: name subtype: name whenCreated: time keyForData: Data. how can we use the keys we already get in the array for the data we also get in the array?

Comment: *In Swift you should rather use Array*, *you explicitly **don't** need* `NSArray`  You don't need `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` for JSON deserialization at all in Swift, never.

Comment: You can cast your data received from the serves directly to an NSArray, than you can access the values

let data: Data = dataFromServer
let myNSArray = try!JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? NSArray